# python serial write hexadecimal string

Tags: python, string, hex, pyserial

I have a string in Python:

```
string = "\x02\x30\x31\x48\x41\x4E\x4F\x56\x45\x52\x03\x38\x39"
```

if i do:

```
serial.write(message)
```

everyting works as expected. Here is the problem:

I have a function which generates the above string. If I debug using print, the exact same string shows up. However, when i try to send it via serial, it does not send it as HEX. It sends a longer text (52 instead of 13 bytes), which is not recognised by the receiving device.

How can I convince python to send a string containing exactly the same as HEX?

Comment: Are you in python 3?

Comment: 13*4=52. Guess where the problem is... it's sending each char in the string as a byte.

Comment: How did you get that string? Your problem lies with your "*function which generates the above string*".  When asking questions on SO, please create the shortest possible *complete* program which demonstrates the error.

Comment: str.decode("hex") solved the problem.